# WinRT equivalent of GetThreadLocale and GetACP

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime

I need to make the following code (from ICU) work on WinRT. Failure happens at [GetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and at [GetACP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
elif U_PLATFORM_USES_ONLY_WIN32_API
   UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
   LCID id = GetThreadLocale();
   const char* locID = uprv_convertToPosix(id, &status);

   if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
       locID = "en_US";
   }
   return locID;
```

and

```
#elif U_PLATFORM_USES_ONLY_WIN32_API
    static char codepage[64];
    sprintf(codepage, "windows-%d", GetACP());
    return codepage;
```

Is there a translation table between old Win32 functions and WinRT?

Comment: WinRT doesn't have new APIs that replace the old, it simply disallows many existing APIs. If the API you want to use says 'desktop apps only' (as the two you linked to do) then it's likely that you're simply out of luck.

Comment: I don't like being SOL. As my math teacher used to say, "surely out of luck!"

Comment: WinRT programs are supposed to be all-unicode so the code page is irrelevant. If you want the user's preferred language, you can use Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages.